# how to access django related field from model methods?

Tags: django

is it possible  to access django related field from model methods?

for example, i have an Author with many Books is it possible to access the list of books from a Model Method in Book model.

```
class Author(models.Model)
    name=charfield

    def mymodelmethod(self)::
        self.book_set????;

class Book:
    author = foreignkey(Author)
    title = charfield
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do:

```
def mymodelmethod(self):
    self.book_set.all()
```

Comment: this does not work for me. self.book_set.all() returns None.

Comment: but if i access book_set.all() outside a model method, eg. inside a view, it works just fine.

Comment: @klauten same problem here. Did you solve yours?

Answer (score 1):

In Python, explicit `return` should be used:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    # ...

    def mymodelmethod(self):
        return self.book_set
```